# How can I hook the color changed event when I selected color is already selected?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have color picker. If I selected different colors means it is fire color changed event. But I select color is already selected color, the Color changed event is not fired. So how can I achieve this requirement or how can hook event for when select color is already selected.

Xaml:

```
<system:SplitButton x:Name="Font_FontColor"  Height="24" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Font_FontColorPicker}">
<system:ColorPickerPalette x:Name="Font_FontColorPicker" system:SkinStorage.VisualStyle="Metro"
                                                                       BlackWhiteVisibility="Both"
                                                                       IsExpanded="True"
                                                                       MoreColorOptionVisibility="Collapsed"/>
```

C#

---

Comment: can I ask why you want this  ? that is the default behaviour of control, as selection has not changed

Comment: For my control faced one small issue. example: In Ms- have fill color.

Comment: So if i not fire the event how can i close the drop down button of color picker. I know its color picker behavior. i ask any other way to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a control behavior. so can make the code for achieve this by below codes

XAML:

```
<syncfusion:SplitButton x:Name="Font_FontColor" Height="24" 
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Font_FontColorPicker}">
<syncfusion:ColorPickerPalette x:Name="Font_FontColorPicker" 
    syncfusion:SkinStorage.VisualStyle="Metro"
    BlackWhiteVisibility="Both" IsExpanded="True" MoreColorOptionVisibility="Collapsed" 
    Color="Red" />
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    bool CanHookEvents = true;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Font_FontColorPicker.ColorChanged += Font_FontColorPicker_ColorChanged;
        //Font_FontColor.IsDropDownOpenChanged += Font_FontColor_IsDropDownOpenChanged;
        Font_FontColorPicker.Loaded += Font_FontColorPicker_Loaded;
    }

    private void Font_FontColorPicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanHookEvents)
        {
            foreach (ColorGroupItem item in FindVisualChildrenOfType<ColorGroupItem>(Font_FontColorPicker))
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += item_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void item_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Font_FontColorPicker.Color.Equals((((sender as ColorGroupItem).Color) as SolidColorBrush).Color))
        {
            // I have closed dropdown. Do your stuff here
            Font_FontColor.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildrenOfType<T>(DependencyObject parent)
   where T : DependencyObject
    {
        List<T> foundChildren = new List<T>();
        int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                foreach (var other in FindVisualChildrenOfType<T>(child))
                    yield return other;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }
        }
    }

    void Font_FontColorPicker_ColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Font_FontColor.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```